# Identify IRC users with largest vocabulary ignoring links and short words

Tags: python, statistics

I wrote this script to figure out which users have the largest vocabulary on my irc server. I would like to see if there's any way to clarify what I consider a very quick script. It outputs a CSV without a header of user, their unique words, most common words and the use of those words.

```
import sys
import json
import string

from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

english_stopwords = stopwords.words('english')


x = defaultdict(Counter)
removepunct = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)

for file in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            line = line.strip().lower()
            # check for system msg in first 20 chars
            if '--' in line[:40]:
                continue
            line = line.translate(removepunct)
            words = line.split()
            if len(words) < 6:
                continue

            user = words[2]
            if user[0] in '@+%&~_[':
                user = user[1:]

            the_user = x[user]
            for word in words[3:]:
                if len(word) > 5 and not(word.startswith('http')) and word not in english_stopwords:
                    the_user[word] += 1

y = [(len(words), user) for user, words in x.items()]
high5 = sorted(y, reverse=True)[:25]
for unique_words, user in high5:
    for word, count in x[user].most_common(10):
        print(user,unique_words,word,count, sep=',')
```

Comment: Will this count every typo as a new word? Is that intentional?

Comment: @Mast Maybe I should add some kind of stemming to it.

Answer (score 1):

**Add comments.**

At the top of the file, explain what it does. Mention the expected input format and the output format. Include paths or "stdin and stdout".

It's a quick script. Add enough that you can understand it in five years. Optimizing throwaway scripts for readability is not worthwhile.